# No puedo escribir en input react js

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un formulario en el que recupero los teléfonos registrados en una base de datos, los datos que recupero los guardo en un array y después con la función map muestro los número en inputs para poder editarlos, pero cuando quiero escribir no puedo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

así tengo el state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {

        telefonos: [],


    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)

    this.handleOpenModalAddPartner = this.handleOpenModalAddPartner.bind(this)
    this.handleCloseModalAddPartner = this.handleCloseModalAddPartner.bind(this)
}
```

y así el input:

```
<div className="form-group row">

    {
        this.state.telefonos.map((telefono)=>
            <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                value={telefono}
                onChange={
                    event => {
                        let telefono = event.target.value
                        this.setState({
                            telefono: telefono
                    })
                    }
                }
            />
        )
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Te aparece algún error en la consola? Sospecho que el detalle está en el onChange ya que estás haciendo un setState a teléfono y teléfono no está en tu state, pero de igual manera react lo agrega. Pero estás asignando como value del input lo que viene de tu array de teléfonos y no del state.

Comment: De hecho no aparece ningún error, es que necesito mostrar el datos en el input y a la vez poder codificarlo, pero si le pongo al value otro valor del state, me aparecen los dos inputs vacios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira, creo que esto te podria funcionar, no se si sea lo mejor respecto a performance, pero es lo que se me ocurre

```
 telefonosHandler (e, idx) => {
    const nuevoTelefono = e.target.value;
    const telefonos = this.state.telefonos;

    telefonos[idx] = nuevoTel;

    this.setState({
       telefonos
    });
 }

return (
      <div className="form-group row">
        {this.state.telefonos.map((telefono, idx) => (
          <input
            key={idx}
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            value={telefono}
            onChange={(e) => this.telefonosHandler(e, idx)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
```

Lo que hace el codigo es que copias el arreglo de telefonos que tienes en tu state , para poder modificarlo y no modificar el state directamente. Despues con ayuda del index que te da el metodo `map` modificas el numero con lo que recibes del input. Por ultimo modificas el arreglo de telefonos que esta en tu state con el la copia modificada de telefonos. Ademas no olvides poner el pop `key` cuando iteras.

Comment: Lo he probado y funciona bien, muchas gracias!!